# Copying Text in Python and Preserving/Finding Special Characters

Tags: python, text

Say I want to copy a passage from The Cask of Amontillado into Python, and then break it down character-by-character ('t','h','e', etc). If I copy the passage in its "proper" format, it will contain special characters like \t and \n.

For the life of my I can't get these special characters to carry over into Python. I've tried several times but instead of recognizing the characters it recognizes spaces and nothing else. I don't know if I'm being too vague but I'm trying to preserve the formatting of large chunks of text when I copy them into Python and break them down, and I can't do it. Are there any reading materials I should look for, or am I just being dense and missing something?

For example, using python's Wikipedia library, if I search for, say, red-ringed pandas:

```
results = wikipedia.search('Ringed Panda', targets)
print results.content
```

I get a block of text without any formatting ("paragraphs" and all their formatting (namely, line breaks/newlines) seem to be replaced by a series of single lines of text.

If I copy any set of formatted text (The Cask of Amontillado, again) into, say, Spyder or even IDLE, the formatting isn't preserved.

Am I just looking at all this wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you "copy" the text? Do you mean copy&paste? What is the original format? PDF? Where do you paste it? An IDE?

Comment: Just copy&paste for now, I wasn't aware that doing it via any other means would change how the format carried over....

Comment: Try creating the simplest, shortest program you can that demonstrates the problem. Copy-paste that short program into your question.

Comment: What format/file is the text in at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use triple quotes and run `list()` on the string.

```
text = '''
hello world
this    is  tabbed
'''

print list(text)
```

Should print out

```
['\n', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\n', 't', 'h', 'i', 's', '\t', 'i', 's', '\t', 't', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd', '\n']
```